# Add an Array of Arrays as an Array under a property to an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to get an output like this:

```
["userDefined": [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]],
 "anotherDefined":[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]]
```

And this is the code I'm using right now:

```
var outterArray = [];
var ultimateArray = [];
//This one works
$(document).on("click", '[id^="addArray"]', function () {
var innerArray = [];
innerArray.push(val1, val2, val3);
outterArray.push(innerArray);    
});

//This one doesn't
$(document).on("click", '[id^="grouUnderProperty"]', function () {
ultimateArray.push(varByUser:outterArray);
});
```

Excuse my broken english and thanks in advance.

Edit 2: 
Epascarrelo said that I was looking for an object instead of an array, and I think that he might be right, but it still doesn't work under an object, I've tried:

```
var ultimateArray = {};
ultimateArray.property.push(outterArray);
ultimateArray.property = outterArray;
```

And it still doesn't work.

Edit 3: I got the answer using a suggestion by Epascarrelo.
This is what is working for me right now:

```
var definedByUser = "textDefinedByUser";
ultimateArray[definedByUser] = outterArray;
```

Is giving me:

```
Object {textDefinedByUser: Array[3]}
```

Thanks for the help and time, and I'll keep the suggestions in mind if I even need to ask abother question.

Comment: um, you want an object, not an array....

Comment: What should the : do? :/

Comment: So I should define it like "var ultimateArray={}"
The thing is, I've tried that and it doesn't work right now...
But you pointed out something for me, I didn't show how the variables are being declared, thanks.
And the ":" is supposed to achieve the asignation of an array under a property of the array. like "userDefinedVar":array

Comment: Are you sure it's `grouUnderProperty` and not something like `groupUnderProperty`? Is it a typo and that's the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: Nah, the grouUnderProperty does work, it shows an alert allright, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What is `varByUser`?

Comment: is a var with the text value defined by the user.